# React - Setting up Route for different set of pages

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-v4

I tried to setup set of Routes for different set of pages I created, I was able to create set of Routes for first set of pages which includes

```
Intro.js  path = /

Login.js path = /login

Dashboard.js path = /dashboard which comes after login.
```

I simply did the following in **app.js**

```
<BrowserRouter>
   <Switch>
      <Route path="/dashboard" component={Dashboard} />
      <Route path="/login" component={Login} />
      <Route path="/" component={Intro} />
   </Switch>
</BrowserRouter>
```

The above works fabulous, but when I land to **Dashboard** which itself has set of Routes specific to Dashboard taking it as root, so my routes should look like **/dashboard/home**, **/dashboard/about** etc

I am confused at this level how should I approach to setup the Routes in Dashboard.

Following are the graphics illustrations of the pages
[image: Into Page]
[image: Login Page]
[image: Dashboard Page]

I would appreciate if you could help me understand whats going on here?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can make Dashboard be a router component as well, so putting in a Switch inside Dashboard will make it so those routes have the `/dashboard` prefix. Something like this

```
<Switch>
  <Route path="/home" component={DashboardHome} /> // localhost:xxxx/dashboard/home
  <Route path="/about" component={DashboardAbout} /> // localhost:xxxx/dashboard/about
</Switch>
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I solved the problem on my own.

I had to simply do the following in **Dashboard.js**

```
<Route path="/dashboard/about" component={About} />
<Route path="/dashboard/settings" component={Settings} />
<Route exact path="/dashboard" component={Home} />
```

It is working as expected.

Hope it helps someone.